# How can I read both string and numeric from excel in a single program in java selenium

Tags: java

```
FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream ("C:\\Users\\sagar.lankegowda\\Desktop\\My workspace\\adt bundle\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\\eclipse\\Excel\\UserCreditanls.xls");
Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(file);
Sheet st=wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
Row r= st.getRow(0);
Cell c=r.getCell(1);
String str="";

if(c.equals(str))
{
     System.out.println(c.getStringCellValue());
}
//System.out.println(str);
else
{   
    System.out.println(c.getNumericCellValue());
}
System.out.println(str);
```

While running this code I am getting an exception as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell
```

Comment: one way is that you can format the cell from Numeric to text in excel sheet. I guess that can solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

What you can do here is just format cell type as desired.
I'm posting code of it below:

```
private static String formatCell(Cell cell)
{
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
    df.setGroupingUsed(false);
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    if (cell == null) {
        return "";
    }
    switch(cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            return "";
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            return Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            return "*error*";
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            return df.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            return df.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        default:
            return "<unknown value>";
    }
}
```

and call:

```
formatCell(row.getCell(0))
```